# How to color potion of an UILabel in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

I want to achieve something like this without using 2 labels.

[image]

How can I create an `UILabel` like this.Please help me.

Comment: Search for AttributedString, it will help for sure

Comment: @Vikky yeas I know it should be something with AttributedString. But How can I color a potion of the UILabel?

Comment: Why can't you use two labels? This would be the easiest way to get even spacing.

Comment: put 2 labels in a stack view and change the background color and text color accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` property of the `NSMutableAttributedString` to achieve the above result

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:yourString)attributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: .redColor() , range: range)
yourLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this output we use `NSAttribute` class

Try below code

```
    //This is for setting border of UILabel
    let labelColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 255.0/255.0, green: 115.0/255.0, blue: 116.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    lblNoOfDays.layer.masksToBounds = true
    lblNoOfDays.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    lblNoOfDays.layer.borderColor = labelColor.cgColor

    //This is value we display
    let strValueTitle = "No of Days"
    let strValue = "04"

    //Attribute dictionary we use
    //NSFontAttributeName:- sets font and it's size
    //NSForegroundColorAttributeName:- sets text colour
    //NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:- sets background color
    let attributeTitle = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: labelColor, NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear]
    let attributeVal = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: labelColor]

    //Implement attributes to string
    let attributTitleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: strValueTitle, attributes: attributeTitle)
    let attributeValue = NSAttributedString(string: strValue, attributes: attributeVal)

    //Append attributed string
    attributTitleString.append(attributeValue)

    //Assign attributed string to label
    lblNoOfDays.attributedText = attributTitleString
    lblNoOfDays.sizeToFit()
```

You need to set padding in `UILabel` for getting desired output.